# Python's sqlite3: How do I change how fetchall() displays the tuples?

Tags: python, sqlite, tuples, fetchall

I am trying to display

```
ID|Class|Start|End|Days|Credit Hours
-------------------------------------
[(1, 'MATH165', '10:30', '11:45', 'M/W/F', '4'), (3, 'MATH165', '10:30', '10:45', 'M/W/F', '4'), (4, 'CSCI230', '4:30', '5:45', 'Tu/Th', '3')]
```

Like this

```
ID|Class|Start|End|Days|Credit Hours
-------------------------------------
[(1, 'MATH165', '10:30', '11:45', 'M/W/F', '4'),
(2, 'W131', '4:30', '5:45', 'M/W', '3'),
(3, 'CSCI230', '4:30', '5:45', 'Tu/Th', '3')]
```

My question: Is it possible to change the format it displays?

Comment: Show you code. Use `for` loop to display every row individually. Or generate full string and replace `),` with `),\n`.

Comment: `c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM Schedule")
    print("""
             """)
    print("ID|Class|Start|End|Days|Credit Hours")
    print("-------------------------------------")
    print(c.fetchall())`

Comment: `for row in  c.fetchall(): print(row)` or `print(str(c.fetchall()).replace("),", "),\n")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Print every row individually

```
for row in c.fetchall(): 
    print(row)
```

or create string using `str()` and replace `),` with `),\n`

```
print( str(c.fetchall()).replace("),", "),\n") )
```

With first method you can do more - you can use string formatting and it will look nicer.

```
for row in c.fetchall(): 
    print("{}|{}|{}|{}|{}|{}".format(*row))
```

See more: [PyFormat.info](https://pyformat.info/)